# Storing Values in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to store values for username and password fields using SharedPreferences and use those values to populate EditText fields. The fields are not being populated and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my login() method that is called when the login button is pressed. In it I set the SharedPreferences values if the login is successful and the check box is checked.

```
public void login() {
        mLoginProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String userNameString = mEmail.getText().toString();
        String passwordString = mPassword.getText().toString();
        ParseUser.logInInBackground(userNameString, passwordString, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                if (parseUser != null) {
                    // Login Successful
                    if (mSaveLogin.isChecked() == true) {
                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("login", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("userName", mEmail.getText().toString());
                        editor.putString("password", mPassword.getText().toString());
                    }
                    mLoginProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    // Login Failed
                    mLoginProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    String exception = e.getMessage().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

In onCreate() I have this code to populate the EditText fields with the SharedPreferences values.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("login", MODE_PRIVATE);
mEmail.setText(pref.getString("userName", ""));
mPassword.setText(pref.getString("password", ""));
```

Comment: Please don't store the password.  Store a salted hash and compare the stored value with the salted hash of the user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `editor.commit()` or `editor.apply()`